# What kind of .apk file is stored in <project-name>/<module-name>/app/release?

Tags: android-studio, directory, hierarchy, subdirectory

I've been looking for the signed file for uploading to an online emulator, but I can't seem to find a legit file. I've been forced to use the .apk in  //release/apk instead of the "suggested" //build/outputs/apk/.
The reason I don't use the suggestion is that there's no file whatsoever under outputs-apk (only a debug file).
What do? Thanks

Comment: I acknowledge that, alas it's not a correct version of my app /design is botched) when uploaded.

Comment: Did the commenter (above mine) delete their purposeful answer?